# Do I need access to a websites database if I want to make an android app to display its goods

Tags: android

If I want to write an android app to display goods from a commercial site,What would I need to access its database and which services would I use to access the database?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need access to this database, this is possible in android and there are tutorials  for this kind of thing if you search it.

You will probably need to ask for permission from the owner of the website in order to gain access as most large commercial websites will have a high level of security on their servers.

Also have a dig around said website as they may just have the APIs you're looking for.

Unfortunately I can't help you much more without any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to create a json object, with information from that website, and parse it in your Android App.

It's called a webservice, you should google it.
With that you can change values in website database directly from your app.

Comment: So Id just like get The website,pick the needed items (images and text) and add it to my listview and imageview,Will I need access to the database and do Jsoup,Rest and Co have the same functions as Json